# Create a 2d array that prints out a snowflake PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x, arraylist, pycharm

I am trying to create a piece of code that will accept a odd number as a input and create a snowflake using this graph of n * n

```
Enter Integer: 5
* . * . *
. * * * .
* * * * *
. * * * .
* . * . *
```

Im pretty sure Im on the the right track

```
n = int(input("Enter odd input: "))
while n % 2 == 0:
  print("Invalid Input.  Input must be odd")
  n = int(input("Enter odd input: "))
snowflake = [["."] * n for i in range(n)]
middle = int((n-1) / 2)
for i in range(n):
  snowflake[i][2] = "*"
  snowflake[2][i] = "*"
  snowflake[i][i] = "*"
  diagnol = 5-i
  snowflake[i][diagnol] = "*"
for i in snowflake:
  for j in i:
    print(j, end=' ')
  print()
print()
```

But I keep getting this error

```
snowflake[i][diagnol] = "*"
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Can someone help edit my code or give me a tip?(This is a homework assignment)

Comment: As you learn how to write code, you should also learn how to debug. [This article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) gives some great tips to get you started. I suggest printing out the values of `snowflake`, `i`, and `diagonal` to see what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Well the first iteration `i=0`, so `diagnol=5` which is indeed outside the bounds of the list.

Comment: Print the index so you will find where you are getting out of range

Comment: @Code-Apprentice thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided not to fix your algorithm, but as a working example to provide my own algorithm:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7NCgIxDITvfYq5pV10F38uCj5JzaEHf@JhupS9@PS1KysIGsiQ@WCYjM/pnrmrlTjh4FLTGKUXRQfimgsMRpTE28UzqPtBR4c2KRLDgK1G01Vzph@wuC@8xqat6dwl3btq78ZinLycKf0jG32U5ZhD4c8nIdT6Ag)

```
n = 9
a = [['.'] * n for i in range(n)]
for i in range(n):
    a[n // 2][i], a[i][n // 2], a[i][i], a[i][n - 1 - i] = ['*'] * 4
print('\n'.join([''.join(a[i]) for i in range(n)]))
```

Output:

```
*...*...*
.*..*..*.
..*.*.*..
...***...
*********
...***...
..*.*.*..
.*..*..*.
*...*...*
```

Answer (score 1):

After debugging it I found that 5 was too big and that some of the code would only work if the input was 5

```
n = int(input("Enter odd input: "))
while n % 2 == 0:
  print("Invalid Input.  Input must be odd")
  n = int(input("Enter odd input: "))
snowflake = [["."] * n for i in range(n)]
middle = int((n-1) / 2)
for i in range(n):
  snowflake[i][middle] = "*"
  snowflake[middle][i] = "*"
  snowflake[i][i] = "*"
  diagnol = n -1 -i
  snowflake[i][diagnol] = "*"
for i in snowflake:
  for j in i:
    print(j, end=' ')
  print()
print()
```